# How to call refresh() on a kendo-grid from an Angular controller?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm attempting to follow several suggestions on refreshing a kendo-grid such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695108/how-can-i-refresh-a-grid-data-source-using-angular-kendo-ui).

The essential is that in the html I have:

```
<div kendo-grid="vm.webapiGrid" options="vm.mainGridOptions">
```

Then in the controller I have:

```
vm.webapiGrid.refresh();
```

Note: I'm using the ControllerAs syntax so I am using "vm" rather than $scope.

My problem is that "vm.webapiGrid" is undefined.  This seems so straightforward, but I'm not sure why it is undefined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the answer.  One other method of refreshing the datasource I read about was to do something like:

```
vm.mainGridOptions.datasource.transport.read();
```

This wasn't working for me as "read" was undefined.  Looking at my datasource definition, I saw the reason, read needs a parameter (in this case "e"):

```
    vm.mainGridOptions = {
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: function (e) {
                    task.getAllTasks(vm.appContext.current.contextSetting).
                        then(function (data) {
                            e.success(data);
                        });
                },
            }
        },
```

To solve, I saved "e" in my scope and then reused it when I wanted to refresh:

```
    vm.mainGridOptions = {
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: function (e) {
                    task.getAllTasks(vm.appContext.current.contextSetting).
                        then(function (data) {
                            e.success(data);
                            vm.optionCallback = e;
                        });
                },
            }
        },
```

and then:

```
if (vm.optionCallback !== undefined) {
   vm.mainGridOptions.dataSource.transport.read(vm.optionCallback);
}
```

Problem solved (I hope).

Answer (score 3):

it's because you are using the options object to trigger the read, you should use the grid reference instead:

```
<div kendo-grid="vm.webapiGrid" options="vm.mainGridOptions">
```

as in:

```
$scope.vm.webapiGrid.dataSource.transport.read();
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score -3):

Add id to the grid and trying refreshing using it.

```
<div kendo-grid="vm.webapiGrid" options="vm.mainGridOptions" id="grid1">
```

In controller use this:

$("#grid1").data('kendoGrid').refresh();

Comment: That starts to get me there (although I'd probably get my fingers chopped off for using a jquery selector).  Problem is that the refresh function is expecting an event.  If I evaluate, I see:  function (e) {
            var that = this,
                length,.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399805/reloading-refreshing-kendo-grid This asnwer also will help

Comment: This tastes more like JQuery. It is a bad practice to use JQuery in an Angular application. So, instead of #grid1 it should be "scope" or "this"