# Kendo UI grid - reload kendo data source after a post request by a button click

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, kendo-ui, grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid with angular js: I have data in the grid and when I click a button, I want to reload the data in the grid with newly updated data.

So, in the angular controller I have:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
                read: function (e) {
                    cache: false;
                    e.success($scope.gridData);
                }
    },
    aggregate: [
                { field: "TOTAL", aggregate: "sum" }         
            ],
            pageSize: 14,
            schema:    {
                model: {
                    id: "id",
                    fields: {
                        name: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                        TOTAL: { editable: false, nullable: true }
                    }
                }
   },
});
```

When I click the button, the below code I have:

```
$scope.CalculateData = function (e) {
            service.Data($scope.gridData)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.statusText == "OK") {
                            $scope.gridData = [];
                            $scope.gridData = response.data;
                            dataSource.read();
                        }
                    },
                        function (response) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    );
        }
```

Even I am calling dataSource.read(); still, the grid data is not reloading with new data.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking the method wrongly. It should be `dataSource.transport.read();`

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
                read: function (e) {
                    cache: false;
                    service.Data($scope.gridData)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.statusText == "OK") {
                            $scope.gridData = [];
                            $scope.gridData = response.data;
                            e.success($scope.gridData);
                            $scope.callback= e;
                        }
                }
    },
    aggregate: [
                { field: "TOTAL", aggregate: "sum" }         
            ],
            pageSize: 14,
            schema:    {
                model: {
                    id: "id",
                    fields: {
                        name: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                        TOTAL: { editable: false, nullable: true }
                    }
                }
   },
});
```

Whenever the callback becomes undefined call your read function with this as parameter to refresh the data

```
  $scope.CalculateData = function(e) {
            if ($scope.callback !== undefined) {
                $scope.mainGridOptions.dataSource.transport.read($scope.callback);
            }
        }
```

Comment: After adding dataSource.transport.read(); i am getting below error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined

Comment: Remove if condition and check

Comment: do i have to call the service service.Data inside transport.read aswell?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324908/how-to-call-refresh-on-a-kendo-grid-from-an-angular-controller. Try to implement in a similar way.

Comment: What is your calculateData() function doing ? And what is $scope .gridData that you are sending to the service in this line service.Data($scope.gridData) conatain ?

Comment: calculateData() just sending edited rows to DB and doing some calculation and giving the result set that I need to load to kendo grid.  $scope .gridData contains all the grid data that I have in the grid. Still no luck with the approach that you mentioned above. Is it something to do with the filter , because before clicking on the button I filtered the data. after did the above code change it is hitting to kendo.data.DataSource read method but nothing happening in the grid.

Comment: Can you try using the set data source method like this var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: "your object returned by ajax"
});

$('#GridKatildigiKurslar').data('kendoGrid').setDataSource(dataSource);

Comment: by trying the above solution it works but I am seeing another issue with this approach...the aggregate method in the calculated field is not showing the sum values.Still showing as 0.

Comment: Is TOTAL type number or date? Can u debug aggregates by dataSource.fetch(function(){
  var results = dataSource.aggregates().TOTAL ;
  console.log(results.sum);
}); ?

Comment: Yeah..it is working fine now but is there no other way do load the data ..seems like so much redundant code... two places i have kendo data source...

Comment: I  think you can remove the service call from your function. The data will get updated in the read method every time you invoke it

Comment: That's the problem I am facing ..without the service call the data is not loading every time by read method.

Comment: Try creating a plunker. There are too many fixes in your code. Withou knowing the flow of code, I can't help you with all the bugs.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ranjan9/pen/mwBrLX?editors=0010 here the sample code of mine...

Comment: yeah, because the api is not setup..i just want you to see the code flow and help me if i am missing anything to fix this...

Comment: You have to do it the way I have mentioned in my answer by defining a callback. Otherwise the e parameter inside your function call will be undefined.